# Text File Permissions Issue

Tags: batch-file, ssis, text-files

What is the default SSIS Account that is used in SSIS packages.

In one of my packages I have a Data Flow task that creates a flat file. A BAT file later runs and creates a file based on information in that .txt file. If I execute the .BAT in Windows Explorer it runs fine. When SSIS tries to execute it I can see the CMD window open and it tries to access the txt file and isnt able to. Says "Unable to access nameoffile.txt"

I assume the issue is that the permissions are probably inherited by the SSIS user account so I am trying to figure out which account that is.

Comment: Try to give `full permission` for `everyone` for the file or the folder and then execute the package

Comment: SSIS doesn't just execute a package---something must make the request, so what is that requester? Is it SQL Server Agent, windows scheduler, a web page, some file watcher process?

Comment: billinkc, I am only hitting START within the VS2008 IDE.

Comment: "Unable to access <filename>" doesn't sound like a standard Windows command prompt error. What is the precise error message? There is a big difference between error 3 ("The system cannot find the path specified") and error 5 ("Access is denied"). What does your batch file do, and does it have any parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the attrib value in dos for that specific folder by attrib -r -s and it worked. It thought it was read-only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it from the IDE then it uses your permissions. Most likely the problem is that your file is locked by some other process in your SSIS package. To verify:

1. Add a PAUSE to your batch file to make it wait for any key.
2. Run your package. While the dos prompt is waiting, go into windows explorer and run your batch file again - you'll find the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows Server 2012 server, with a SQL Server 2012 database.

Adding Modify, Read, Write permissions to the folder containing the required file to the NETWORK SERVICE user seems to work for me.